# Python3 - find a row from csv file that starts with

Tags: python, readline, strip

I have a script that finds a row in csv file that starts with certain text.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    line = f.readline()
    nline = 1
    while line.strip() != 'start time = 21.08.2022 1 11:35:04':
        line=f.readline()
        nline+=1
```

QUESTION: Is it possible to change this script to work also with 'start time ='
not with the whole line 'start time = 21.08.2022 1 11:35:04' ?

If I just change it, the scripts gets frozen.

Comment: "Is it possible?" Yes. I suggest googling "python find a line that starts with". Someone has probably already posted an answer for you.

Comment: thank you for the tip. I understand that I must use: startswith("start time =")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Code-Apprentice, I found the solution. Instead of using:

```
while line.strip() != 'start time = 21.08.2022 1 11:35:04':
```

I can use:

```
if line.startswith("start time ="):
```

Thank you!